# jQuery Mobile app force browser to ignore cached pages

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I wrote a jQuery Mobile app which over 200 people are using heavily on daily basis and I have a following problem. Every time I change something in the app (either HTML, CCS or js) users are still working on old version. It's like their mobile browsers are not detecting that files have changed... They have to clear browser cache in order to get latest version.
Is there a way for me to force browser to ignore cached version and re-download current ???

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do we control web page caching, across all browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/how-do-we-control-web-page-caching-across-all-browsers)

Comment: deblocker - Thanks for answering. Yes, at least it pointed me to right direction...I'm testing it now - probably web.config is the best way to do it with single page HTML5/jQuery mobile app - I tried adding it directly to meta tags but it says straight  - it doesn't work with html5...

Answer (score 0):

Under IIS (7+):

- The quick way:

In IIS Manager, select Your Website, double-click *HTTP Response Headers* and then choose the Action **Set Common Headers**.

This will open the dialog window *Set Common HTTP Response Headers*.

If You check **Expire Web content** and select **Immediately**, this will send the `Cache-Control: no-cache` to the browser for all files.

- Fine-tuning:

[Download](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) and install the URL Rewrite Extension for IIS. This will add the **URL Rewrite** feature.

Add a new **Blank rule** and set it as follows:

```
Name: ResponseNoCache (or whatever You like)
Match: Server Variable
Variable Name: RESPONSE_CACHE_CONTROL
Variable value: Matches the pattern 
Using: Wildcards 
Pattern: *

Action type: Rewrite
Value: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
```

Now, to get more granularity, You can set the *preconditions*.

Click on **Precondition**, select *Create New Precondition...*

Just for instance, I am fine with filtering by file extension:

```
Name: NoCacheRequestFiles (or whatever You like)
Using: Regular Expressions
```

Click on the **Add..** button, the *Add Condition* dialog window will open.

```
Condition input: {REQUEST_FILENAME} 
Check if input string: Matches the pattern
Pattern: \.html|\.js|\.css
```

After that, You need to click the **Apply** action and **restart** the IIS.

The `web.config` then looks like this:

```
<rewrite>
  <outboundRules>
    <rule name="ResponseNoCache" preCondition="NoCacheRequestFiles" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
      <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_CACHE_CONTROL" pattern="*" />
      <action type="Rewrite" value="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
    </rule>
    <preConditions>
      <preCondition name="NoCacheRequestFiles">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" pattern="\.html|\.js|\.css" />
      </preCondition>
    </preConditions>
  </outboundRules>
</rewrite>
```

Now, You can check inside the Chrome Developer Tools (or whatever You prefer) that the IIS is effectively sending that `Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate` response header.

---

Additional info:

I am using also Static and Dynamic Compression as well. So, I noticed that IIS is caching the g-zipped files depending on two additional parameters:

- frequentHitThreshold
- frequentHitTimePeriod

I didn't investigate further the interaction between compressed content and cache-control headers, because the whole is a fairly [complex topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/httpcompression/) subject to frequent changes and [hotfixes](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2877816/vary-header-is-overwritten-as-accept-encoding-after-you-enable-dynamic). But, it would be nice to hear a feedback from You, if this solutions works well also for mobile devices browsers.